# PHP OOP Based CMS - Displaying Separate Pages

Tags: php, class, oop, content-management-system, subclass

I'm building a CMS using PHP and OOP - it's a bit of a learning project, something to improve my OOP skills while giving me the motivation of having a final target in mind.

I've come to actually coding the back end pages - I just have a question on how to best structure the app in terms of folders, files etc.

I have a folder of classes, some of which I plan to make use of in the front end website. One such class is the Page class which deals with loading the template (header, content and footer) which will work fine for the front end I'm sure. The back end is a different story however, obviously none of the pages (add/edit page, add/edit user etc) will be stored in the database so how should I handle the outputting of these pages?

Am I best creating sub classes of the Page class and setting the content up there? Or would it be better to create a new PHP file for each page? I'm leaning towards just using sub classes but that could lead to a pretty heavy file (Page class, sub classes of add page, edit page etc).

Any advice on the best way to go about this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do more or less this structure (MVC architectural pattern):

```
-MyCMS
--assets
----css
----img
----js
----templates
------pages
------partials
--------forms
--------grids
--conf
--src
----Controller
------Dispatcher
----Form
----Model
------DataMapper
----Routing
----View
------Renderer
--test
```

I think it is a bad idea to maintain all of your classes in the same folder, they should be grouped logically. This is just an example, you don't need to have these components in your `src` folder, but will give you an idea of how to organize your componets.

Your class `Page` should be generic, building a page from templates in `assets/templates/pages` an not subclass it for each different page.

Comment: you are missing the "tests" folder =P

Comment: In deed, but I don't know if he use unit tests =P... But I'll change there.

Comment: I don't use unit tests... yet! I think this is the way I'll eventually go. I like the idea of having core code and letting the template do all the styling alone but that's not as practical as having full control over page output within a template file.

Comment: But you will have full control. For each different page you shall have, you create a new template in `templates/pages`. Your class `Page` should only allow you to modify these templates as you want.

Comment: That's what I meant, I'll actually have more control using template files. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

Put each sub-class into a separate file. Have the file name and the class name correspond, so you can set up class auto-loading later.